# Minimum Value Tuples when Values are stored in another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a list

`[{0: [0, 1, 2, 3], 1: [4]}, {2: [5, 6, 7, 8], 3: [9]}, {4: [10, 11, 12]}]`

and another dictionary

```
    servicesdict = { 0 : {'cost' : 30},
        1 : {'cost' : 50},
        2 : {'cost' : 70},
        3 : {'cost' : 20},
        4 : {'cost' : 20},

        5 : {'cost' : 10},
        6 : {'cost' : 20},
        7 : {'cost' : 50},
        8 : {'cost' : 70},
        9 : {'cost' : 20},

        10 : {'cost' : 20},
        11 : {'cost' : 20},
        12 : {'cost' : 40},
        }
```

I wrote 
    `{k: [min(v, key = lambda x:servicesdict[x]['cost'])]for item in newlist for k, v in item.items()}`to get the minimum cost of the list element in each subdictionary of the list

This produces the minimum list element not just the cost

`{0: [0], 1: [4], 2: [5], 3: [9], 4: [10]}`

How do I get the corresponding cost as well? That is, the output should be

`{0: [0, 20], 1: [4, 20], 2: [5, 10], 3: [9, 20], 4: [10, 20]}`

Comment: Shouldn't your final result include `[0, 20]` for the key `0`, because in `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, the minimum value is actually `20` for `3`, not `30`?

Comment: @Ajax1234, I think it should be `[3, 20]` as shown by other answerers. There's still a bit of confusion as OP's code outputs `[3]` for key `0` and not `[0]`.

Comment: Yea sorry, that was a typo, I have corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
servicesdict = {
    0: {'cost': 30},
    1: {'cost': 50},
    2: {'cost': 70},
    3: {'cost': 20},
    4: {'cost': 20},

    5: {'cost': 10},
    6: {'cost': 20},
    7: {'cost': 50},
    8: {'cost': 70},
    9: {'cost': 20},

    10: {'cost': 20},
    11: {'cost': 20},
    12: {'cost': 40},
}

newlist = [{0: [0, 1, 2, 3], 1: [4]}, {2: [5, 6, 7, 8], 3: [9]}, {4: [10, 11, 12]}]
mins = {
    k: min([[servicesdict[x]['cost'], x] for x in sublist])
    for dct in newlist
    for k, sublist in dct.items()
}

print(mins)
# {0: [20, 3], 1: [20, 4], 2: [10, 5], 3: [20, 9], 4: [20, 10]}
```

Basically convert each sublist to a list of `[cost, id]` pairs and take the min of that. The default comparison for lists will compare the cost first. If you make `[id, cost]` pairs instead then you need to provide a key to sort by cost.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest approach here is to use the obtained list:

```
d = {k: [min(v, key = lambda x:servicesdict[x]['cost'])] for item in newlist 
        for k, v in item.items()}
```

And add the corresponding `cost` with the bellow dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: [*v, servicesdict[v[0]]['cost']] for k,v in d.items()}
# {0: [3, 20], 1: [4, 20], 2: [5, 10], 3: [9, 20], 4: [10, 20]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `min` twice:

```
d = [{0: [0, 1, 2, 3], 1: [4]}, {2: [5, 6, 7, 8], 3: [9]}, {4: [10, 11, 12]}]
servicesdict = {0: {'cost': 30}, 1: {'cost': 50}, 2: {'cost': 70}, 3: {'cost': 20}, 4: {'cost': 20}, 5: {'cost': 10}, 6: {'cost': 20}, 7: {'cost': 50}, 8: {'cost': 70}, 9: {'cost': 20}, 10: {'cost': 20}, 11: {'cost': 20}, 12: {'cost': 40}}
result = {a:[min(b), min(servicesdict[i]['cost'] for i in b)] for c in d for a, b in c.items()}
```

Output:

```
{0: [0, 20], 1: [4, 20], 2: [5, 10], 3: [9, 20], 4: [10, 20]}
```

Edit: if you want the first element in each list to be the key of the minimum value in `servicesdict`, then `min` with key` can be applied:

```
result = {a:[min(b, key=lambda x:servicesdict[x]['cost']), min(servicesdict[i]['cost'] for i in b)] for c in d for a, b in c.items()}
```

Output:

```
{0: [3, 20], 1: [4, 20], 2: [5, 10], 3: [9, 20], 4: [10, 20]}
```